# Why do TINA simulator have not a single optocoupler in it's library?

Tags: simulation, opto-isolator

I am using Texas Instrument's TINA simulation software. I want to do simulation of circuit i.e. that can be used as USB charging device for smartphones .It is a buck converter that converts 110Vdc into 5Vdc,2A. I have a schematic in which there is one opto-coupler (**O1**)named [TCMT1100](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83510/tcmt1100.pdf)  not available in the TINA library. There is no  TINA library file of TCMT1100 available on internet too. When I tried checking for alternate component ,it is also not available . Even there is not a single opto-coupler available in TINA library

So can anybody help me regarding this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TINA is a free tool supplied by Texas Instruments to help in designing products using TI parts. It is a TI business tool. The TCMT1100 is made by Vishay, and Vishay does have [SPICE model](http://www.vishay.com/optocouplers/list/product-83510/) for this part, so you can technically include this into TINA library as a subcircuit or other [proper import method](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slva527).

Comment: I have imported it into netlist. successfully compiled but why am I getting the [following error](https://1fichier.com/?sbnseobszr) while doing new macro wizard?

Comment: and when i select choose shapes from library ,it show [this](https://1fichier.com/?3kvntri7z9) .I am unable to select **next** option

Comment: I have answered the question why TINA does not have models for optocouplers. To find answers about porting SPICE netlists into TINA, please go to TI TINA user groups.